# Display footer once in a multiple-page in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, footer

I am customising a SSRS report in MS report builder 2014.
Current Condition
In this report, the body displays invoice info per customer ID, which may varies from 1 to multiple pages. e.g. the customer TEST001, there are 100 invoice line from INVC10001.... to INVC10100 with coresponding amount info, which is pirnted in 3 pages.
The report will start a new page for each customer ID.
The Remittance info (contains variable data and dynamic data) in the footer currently displays on  every single page of the report. Take TEST001 as example, the payment bank info will be printed 3 pages under TEST001.
New Requirement
for those customer ID report lasting more than 1 pages, how can I display the remittance info on last page of the footer only under that customer ID(e.g. only print the bank info on page 3)?

Comment: can you have screenshot regarding your issue ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please always add examples to your question, so it will be easier for users to understand your question and help you. You might also want to read through this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks. I added an example now.

Comment: Is your question simply **How do I display a footer on the final page only?**

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in the **Hidden** property for any objects you **only want to show on the final page**.

```
=iif(Globals!PageNumber=Globals!TotalPages,false,true)
```

Comment: You need to edit your question title to read, simply, **How do I show a summary at the end of every group.** and then read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220573.aspx

Comment: @peter Excellent, it seems work for me now. but the footer place are held in  the first a few pages. Anyway, the initial question is solved. Let me investigate the next issue of how to solve the held blank place from the footer section. Thanks again.